# Implement connections (FB-like) between users on a RoR app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, social-networking

I'm trying to implement a Self-Referential Association in order to achieve a connections list for a given user (like FB or linkedIn does).

All the tutorials around implement the "following/follower" model that is a bit diffrent from this one, so... let's get creative:

So besides the user table, I have a user_connections table with the fields:

- requester_id
- requested_id
  (...)

And "modeled" it the following way:

User.rb:

```
  # Connections
  has_many :user_connections, foreign_key: 'requester_id' # people that i invited to connect to me
  has_many :user_inverse_connections, foreign_key: 'requested_id', class_name: 'UserConnection' # people that invited me to connect with them

  has_many :i_invited, source: :requester, through: :user_connections
  has_many :invited_me, source: :requested, through: :user_inverse_connections

  def connections
    i_invited.merge(invited_me)
  end
```

I tried to test this:

```
2.0.0-p247 :003 > u.connections
  User Load (84.3ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` INNER JOIN `user_connections` ON `users`.`id` = `user_connections`.`requester_id` INNER JOIN `user_connections` ON `users`.`id` = `user_connections`.`requested_id` WHERE `user_connections`.`requester_id` = 1 AND `user_connections`.`requested_id` = 1
```

But as may noticed, it didn't work out:

> Mysql2::Error: Not unique table/alias: 'user_connections': SELECT
>   `users`.* FROM `users` INNER JOIN `user_connections` ON `users`.`id` =
>   `user_connections`.`requester_id` INNER JOIN `user_connections` ON
>   `users`.`id` = `user_connections`.`requested_id` WHERE
>   `user_connections`.`requester_id` = 1 AND
>   `user_connections`.`requested_id` = 1

Am I doing this really the right way?

Furtherly, any tips on how I can achieve "connection" search for 2nd level and others?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question what's the difference between FB-Like and follower followed model?

Comment: I can follow you but that doesen't mean that you're following me. In FB it doesen't work like that :)

Comment: you can make a table with attributes follower_id, followes_id See my answer shortly

Answer (score 1):

You can make a table with attributes follower_id, follows_id

And just record who every user follows in that table. This is a Many-Many relationship
So John can be following Jane even though Jane does not follow John.

Comment: Cool, thanks. 
Now how can I get who I'm following and who follows me on the same hash/method (what I tried to do on the `connections` method)?

Meanwhile I found this gem - https://github.com/raw1z/amistad - I'll probably give it a try.

Comment: you can join the followes_id to user_id, something like Select username from followtable join users as u ON u.id= follows_id WHERE follower_id =1

Comment: you can also check rails documentation for joins and many to many associations

Answer (score 0):

```
def connections
   i_invited + invited_me
end
```

This solved the problem...

But with a pay-off: (haven't tested yet, but I think) it's an array instead of a relation..

Comment: This is not a good idea. It will bring your app server to its knees when you have too many users. use database to count or sum attributes